# Are esc_* functions enough safe in WordPress? (like esc_url, esc_attr, esc_title)

Tags: wordpress

WordPress has a number of built-in validation/sanitization functions. However, as we see, there are two kinds of such group:

- `sanitize_`* (like `sanitize_key`, `sanitize_title`, ...)
- `esc_`* (like `esc_url`, `esc_attr`, ...)

My Question: Are `esc_`* functions enough safe in WordPress? 
I mean, in such cases:

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="orderby" value="' . esc_attr( $_REQUEST['search_term'] ) . '" />';
```

is that safe enough, or we should still use extra sanitization, like:

```
sanitize_title(esc_attr( $_REQUEST['search_term'] ))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion these functions and their documentation are pretty clear at which places these functions should be used and what they do. [esc_attr](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_url) escapes attributes in HTML tags and [sanitize_title](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_title) sanitizes the title and removes HTML, PHP etc. Since attributes (for `esc_attr`) are (only) used inside HTML tags and HTML tags will be removed by `sanitize_title` it makes no sense to use `esc_attr` inside `sanitize_title`: any escaped attributes inside HTML will be removed together with the full HTML tag.

The `esc_...` and `sanitize_...` functions itself are secure as long as they are used for the purpose which they were designed for (and which is documented). If one instead tries to use `esc_attr` to escape a URL etc then this does not match the documented purpose and likely provides not the intended security.

Comment: thanks, but the reason I asked here, is if there are any security issues with them. So, as i see many themes/plugins use `esc_`, can you directly answer:     are `esc_` functions safe enough in `html` so we dont need the `sanitize_` functions when `esc_` is used, right?

Comment: @T.Todua: the `esc_...` and `sanitize_...` functions are secure as long as they are used for the purpose which they were designed for (and which is documented). If one instead tries to use `esc_attr` to escape a URL etc then this does not match the documented purpose and likely provides not the intended security.

Comment: please include this last comment in answer and i will mark it. thanks.